# Is there a way to also set AWS metadata values when saving a data frame as a parquet file to S3 using df.to_parquet?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, parquet

When I put an object in python, I can set the metadata at the time. Example:

```
self.s3_client.put_object(
 Bucket=self._bucket,
 Key=key,
 Body=body,
 ContentEncoding=self._compression,
 ContentType="application/json",
 ContentLanguage="en-US",
 Metadata={'other-key':'value'}
)
```

It seems like both pyarrow and fastparquet don't let me pass those particular keywords despite the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) saying that extra keywords are passed.

This saves the data how I want it to, but I can't seem to attach the metadata with any syntax that I try.

```
df.to_parquet(s3_path, compression='gzip')
```

If there was an easy way to compress the parquet and convert it to a bytestream.

Would rather not write the file twice (either to local then transfer to AWS or twice on AWS)

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  Found it quicker than I thought.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

#read in data to df. 
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')

body = io.BytesIO()
df.to_parquet(
    path=body,
    compression="gzip",
    engine="pyarrow",
)
bucket='MY_BUCKET'
key='prefix/key'
s3_client.put_object(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=key,
    Body=body.getvalue(),
    ContentEncoding='gzip',
    ContentType="application/x-parquet",
    ContentLanguage="en-US",
    Metadata={'user-key':'value'},
)
```